# I need to get the numbers of Users for each language

Tags: sql-server, angular, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a list of languages and I need to show how many users subscribe to each.

I work on my project with Angular 13 and ASP.NET Core 6 and SQL Server but there are two blocked ways

1. Use Angular services in NgFor but return infinite loops and crash.
2. Use .NET to return the list of languages and loop a second query to get count users but not work.
3. The last is to create something with SQL Server (I don't know how)

[[image: Table languages][1]]

[image: table users]

Comment: `ntext` and `text` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) And for storing an *image* (in your `Languages` table), I would strongly recommend using `varbinary(max)` (why store an image as text??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your API you will need to return a payload that you can use to show the results you expect. From the API layer, you need to access the database and transform data to the meet the former challenge. The query to obtain the results is rather straightforward.

```
SELECT 
    L.lang_id,
    L.title,
    L.description,
    L.image,
    COUNT(*) as UserCount
FROM
    Languages L
    INNER JOIN Users U on U._id_lang = L.id_lang
GROUP BY
    L.id_lang
```

Comment: That return Error The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator                                          
   SELECT 
    L.id_Lang,
    L.title,
    L.img,
    COUNT(*) AS UserCount
FROM
    dbo.Languages L
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users U on U.id_lang = L.id_Lang
GROUP BY
    L.id_Lang ,L.title , L.img

Comment: Sorry, try again, I had an errant underscore in the orginal query.

Comment: Thank you     SELECT 
    CAST(L.id_Lang AS NVARCHAR(200)) AS idLang ,
    CAST(L.title AS NVARCHAR(200)) AS TitleLang ,
    CAST(L.img AS NVARCHAR(200)) AS ImgLang ,
    COUNT(*) AS UserCount
FROM
    dbo.Languages L
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users U on U.id_lang = L.id_Lang
GROUP BY
    CAST(L.id_Lang AS NVARCHAR(200)) ,CAST(L.title AS NVARCHAR(200)) , CAST(L.img AS NVARCHAR(200))

Answer (score 0):

@ross bush thank you

```
SELECT 
    CAST(L.id_Lang AS NVARCHAR(200)) AS idLang ,
    CAST(L.title AS NVARCHAR(200)) AS TitleLang ,
    CAST(L.img AS NVARCHAR(200)) AS ImgLang ,
    COUNT(*) AS UserCount
FROM
    dbo.Languages L
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users U on U.id_lang = L.id_Lang
GROUP BY
    CAST(L.id_Lang AS NVARCHAR(200)) ,CAST(L.title AS NVARCHAR(200)) , CAST(L.img AS NVARCHAR(200))
```

[image: result]

Comment: No problem. I am just curious as to why you need to cast everything in the sql statement?